# Why do some Hindus observe fast during the month of "Shravan"?

Tags: rituals, tradition, fasting

Why do some Hindus observe fast during the lunar month of "Shravan"?
What does it signify?
Is it prescribed by the holy texts?

Comment: I don't know if anybody observes fast, but I know that many do not eat non-veg food.

Answer (score 2):

**Scientific Reason**

> During Shravana monsoon is at its peak and there is less sunlight, it makes digestive system weak. During this period, water-borne diseases spread rapidly. Fasts detoxify the system.

**Religious Reason**

> It is believed that one who carries out the Shravan Somvara Vrat has their prayers answered. During the day devotees consume only non-solid foods such as milk, buttermilk, fruit juice and fruits. The devotee then breaks his/her fast (eats his/her evening meal) after praying to Lord Shiva.

Don't know whether its prescribed in holy texts or not.